# FsUnit and NUnit without using objects?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, f#, nunit

Here is a working trivial test:

```
module Tests

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

[<TestFixture>] 
type simple ()=
   [<Test>] member test.
    ``tautology`` ()=
           true |> should be True
```

My project doesn't use any of F#'s OOP features yet - can I write tests without objects, or is that just how NUnit works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FsUnit/NUnit also supports let-bounds. Here is an example from [FsUnit's official announcement](http://freshbrewedcode.com/danmohl/2012/01/03/announcing-fsunit-1-0/):

```
module Test.``equalWithin assertions``

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

[<Test>]
let ``should equal within tolerance when less than``() =
    10.09 |> should (equalWithin 0.1) 10.11

[<Test>]
let ``should not equal within tolerance``() =
    10.1 |> should not ((equalWithin 0.001) 10.11)
```

Another example of using static functions could be found in [FsUnit's github page](https://github.com/dmohl/FsUnit/blob/master/Examples/NUnit/BowlingGame.fsx).